# How to check for illegal characters on swift. (Illegal characters for Windows, Android & IOS)

Tags: android, ios, swift, regex, windows

I'm making a special file saving system for IOS and possibly mac.

My program will basically allow the user to write the name of the file, but before I do that I need to check for illegal characters that exist for IOS, Windows, and Android since they will all be probably be passed into another system via the user's own decision (Like through email or  USB for example).

In general if you try to bring any file with an illegal "name" into another system, the file will either become corrupted or not be passed into the system at all.

The problem is with my code is that it ONLY works if there is ONE character in the string in total. If the former situation, the regex checker doesn't detect anything regardless of where or how many illegal characters are there.

This is my code.

```
 //Validates the string for illegal file name characters
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635391/java-function-to-return-if-string-contains-illegal-characters
    func hasIllegalCharacters(locationNameString: String) -> Bool{
        //do {

            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]");
        let illegalRegEx = "[~#@*+%{}<>\\[\\]|\"\\_^]"
        //let ipAddressRegEx = "|\\?*<\":>+[]/'"
                      let trimmedString = locationNameString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                      let validateName = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", illegalRegEx)
                      let isIllegal = validateName.evaluate(with: trimmedString)

        if(isIllegal){
         print("has illegal chars")
        }
        else{
            print("no illegal detected")
        }

            return isIllegal

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension String {
   var containsSpecialCharacter: Bool {
      let regex = ".*[^A-Za-z0-9].*"
      let testString = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
      return testString.evaluate(with: self)
   }
}
```

Regex makes lists all non illegal characters and then testString tests if the if the string matches with the characters in regex. It will return True or False

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: This is correct, BUT there is one thing wrong with his answer: When using this check, it would always be true, special character or not IF there is a space in between characters. For example "Hello world" would be true to this case. To compensate we need to trim spaces between characters within the check.